# What are the open source equivalents of Apple's Accelerate Framework libraries?

Tags: c, open-source, fortran, hpc, accelerate-framework

If we take a look under the umbrella of Accelerate Framework we will see several libraries:
[image: Accelerate Framework]

I know that BLAS and LAPACK are open source and that the same code used otherwhere can be compiled against Accelerate.
But what about vForce, vMathLib (and other in vMisc) and vDSP? Is there any open source equivalent for those libraries?

### EDIT:

Let me elaborate it a little more (only know I have knowledge enough to do so). Basically, vDSP, vFoce and vMathLib are vector oriented libraries. So, if we have a vector and want to calculate a component-wise function over it, say sin() and cos(), it is faster to use vvsincos() from Accelerate because it will pipeline the calculations of sin() and cos() for all the entries in the vector, which is faster than using a for loop over the vector.
Simply expanding those functions in Taylor-series and using trigonometric relations, we see that there are several repetitive calculations going on and the framework tries to avoid this.

This is the same for FFT under vDSP and so forth

Than, my problem is: what is the BEST open source equivalent to this? And if I develop my project under Accelerate, how can I distribute it using open source tools without needing to rewrite my code?

Comment: If you tell us what vForce, vMisc and vDSP provide someone might be able to help.  Me, I'm too indolent to first find that out on your behalf.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: vDSP is an assortment of signal-processing functions, from simple vector additions to FFTs. vForce is, roughly, libm for arrays (e.g., sine of each array element). vMathLib contains an assortment of routines, including some wide-integer operations, libm-like functions for SIMD objects, and some BLAS functions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: to correct you slightly, vMathLib contains only math library functions on SIMD arrays.  The big integer and legacy BLAS stuff is in other headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stephen Canon (@stephencanon) was kind enough to answer me on twitter:

"[OpenCV](http://opencv.org) provides some of the vImage functionality and the [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) has some overlap with vDSP.  Neither is a complete equivalent and neither is interface-compatibile, so no drop-in replacement like there is with BLAS/LAPACK."